# Drools 7.57.0. mateSpace oom

Tags: drools

I ues Drools 7.57.0 version ，Each time a rule is added, mateSpace usage increases and is not recycled

```
Map<String, KieBaseModel> kieBaseModels = kieModuleModel.getKieBaseModels();
        KieBaseModel kieBaseModel = kieBaseModels.get(kieBaseName);
        if (kieBaseModel == null) {
            kieBaseModel = kieModuleModel.newKieBaseModel(kieBaseName);
            KieSessionModel kieSessionModel = kieBaseModel.newKieSessionModel(kieBaseName);}
```

```
List<String> packages = kieBaseModel.getPackages();
            if (CollUtil.isEmpty(packages) || !packages.contains(pkg)) {
                kieBaseModel.addPackage(pkg);
            }
```

```
kieFileSystem.write(filePath, engineRule.getScript());
kieFileSystem.writeKModuleXML(kieModuleModel.toXML());
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
kieContainer.updateToVersion(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
```

Comment: Assuming you mean `metaSpace` and not "mateSpace", then this makes sense, doesn't it? You're reading new rules into memory, they need to live somewhere.

Comment: And, at least in your example, you don't ever seem to be _deleting_ anything from memory. So it just accumulates.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `KieRepository.removeKieModule(ReleaseId)` to remove old kieModules.

References:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1044007
- https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-381
- https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/commit/88672e348ed9d32c3f74683e91f727c80754350f